# Using text-align: center on a block with changing value

Tags: html, css

I currently have a block with a number centered in it, and on hover I want to increase the number, however, with the Google webfont I am using (Montserrat), the characters seem to have different widths, and when you hover the entire number shifts slightly to be centered.

Here is a quick JSFiddle to illustrate the problem on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehpv2/

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="one">46</div>
    <div class="two">47</div>
</div>
```

On hover, the 46 disappears and the 47 appears in its place.

Is there a way to get the "4" in the 46/47 to not move when aligned in the center? And only change the 6/7?

I can't think of a way to do it! This only happens in some fonts, and I want to use Montserrat, so hoping there's a clever trick to achieve this!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `text-align:center` and setting the divs to `display:inline-block`, give them a width and use `margin:0 auto` to center them.

```
.one,.two {
    width:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r4QHg/)**

Comment: While this works for the current scenario, it would not work when the first digit is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You want the characters to have the same width, with a monospaced font this is easy, but you can't really force a font into monospace using CSS only.

A solution is to place the characters in separate elements and give them a fixed width.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="one"><span class="char">4</span><span class="char">6</span></div>
    <div class="two"><span class="char">4</span><span class="char">7</span></div>
</div>
```

```
.char {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehpv2/3/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ehpv2/5/)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

    .block { font-size: 4em; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; width:100%; height: 100px; text-align: center; }

    .one { display: inline-block;width:60px; }

    .two { display: none; width:60px;  }
    .block:hover .two { display: inline-block; }
    .block:hover .one { display: none; }
```